# Impurity transfer

Tags: salat, practical-islam, waswasa

I have a question, someone passed stool and didn't washed hands with soap rather touched furniture corner and later my relative putted pillow on that furniture and slept. It's been weeks and now after using double pillow case would sleeping with wet hairs makes my hairs impure?

Comment: This lacks detail. Washing with soap is not required for the hand to be considered pure. Even washing with water is not required unless you actually touched the feces with your hand.

Answer (score -2):

**Bismillah Hir Rahmaan Nir Raheem**

**As Salaamu 3laykum,**

I hope you and your family are doing well.

You should be fine. Even if he didn't clean himself there was nothing impure on his hand (like urine or feces).

Also if someone uses the restroom to urinate and does not touch his private parts with his hands then he is clean. If he didn't clean his private parts then he cannot pray in those clothes until they are cleaned.

However, touching the private part doesn't make your hands unclean. Your hands are unclean when there is something dirty (urine or feces on them). If they are washed with water then everything is fine.

I would advise from thinking too much on this unless you see it or smell it from his hands. Otherwise you might fall into unnecessary doubt which might lead to OCD (obsessive compulsive disorder).

**Have a Nice Day!**

**Note #1:** If you downvote my answer, please be courteous and say why you downvoted in a comment below.

**Note #2:** This is my own personal answer that I have derived from what I have researched.